# ASP.NET Core 6 jQuery Validation not working

Tags: jquery, razor, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm writing a simple web app with ASP.NET Core 6 and I want to use jQuery validation.

I include jQuery, jquery-validate and jquery-validation-unobstrusive in wwwroot, then I include them in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@using LinarLedManagement.Extensions;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - LinarLedManagement</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/LinarLedManagement.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    
    <script src="~/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    
    <script src ="~/js/bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
html, body { height: 100%; }
</style>
<body style="height:100%; width:100%;">
    <header>
       <!-- aqui va el partial view del menu-->
    </header>
    
    <div class="container-fluid w-100 h-100">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Then I created a simple view:

```
@model LoginModel
<script>
    let login = new Login();
</script>

<div class="container h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    @using(Html.BeginFormPostWithID("Login","Login","loginForm")){
        <div class="card" style="width:25rem">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.UserName,new {@class = "col-sm-4 col-form-label"})
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.UserName,new {@class = "form-control"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mb-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Password,new {@class = "col-sm-4 col-form-label"})
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password,new {@class = "form-control"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary align-self-center col-sm-4" value ="@Resources.Resource.Login" onclick="login.submit()"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

With a Typescript file:

```
class Login() {
    constructor() {
        LoginValidation.validateLoginFields();
    }

    public submit() {
        $('#loginForm').validate();
    }
}

class LoginValidation {
    constructor() { }

    public static validateLoginFields() {
        $('#UserName').rules("add", {
            required: true
        });
        $('#Password').rules("add", {
            required: true
        });
    }
}
```

But when I click in the button it always get a

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function...

And this is the wwwroot structure:

[wwwroot structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdBay.png)

Could someone help me please?

Comment: First big problem is that you're including jQuery twice... once in the `head` and again in the `body`.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much! I just delete the include in the body and now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky) said in the comment, the problem was that I was including twice jQuery (once in the `head` and another in the `body`) I just delete the include of the `body` and it works now!